# Array objects jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an array of this kind.

```
0: {ID: 5, post_author: "1", post_date: "2017-10-26 13:02:24", post_date_gmt: "2017-10-26 13:02:24", post_content: "dfasdfasdfasdfasgfsgdsgdsfg", …}
1:{ID: 1, post_author: "1", post_date: "2017-09-26 10:43:50", post_date_gmt: "2017-09-26 10:43:50", post_content: "Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!", …}
2 : {ID: 4439, post_author: "1", post_date: "2017-05-12 09:11:51", post_date_gmt: "2017-05-12 09:11:51", post_content: "<p style="text-align: justify;"><b>During 2 days, …}
3:{ID: 3970, post_author: "1", post_date: "2017-04-14 11:48:44", post_date_gmt: "2017-04-14 11:48:44", post_content: "<p style="text-align: justify;"><strong>April 10, ….</p>↵https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iq437v6Z14o", …}
```

how do I refer to each id in this array, and create a new array with the values I addressed

Comment: can you please elaborate? an example array of what you need will be enough.

Comment: What do you mean with "the values I adressed". Also try to use a meaningful question title... 3 nouns is not a question.

Comment: i want select all ID values in each element of array and push this values in new array

Comment: what "values". do you mean you want an array of all IDs, without the rest of the objects?

Comment: `$.each(arr, function(i, v){ console.log( i + ' element is: ' + v["ID"] + ", " + v["post_author"] /* etc etc etc*/)})`

Comment: yes, only values from ID (5,1,4439,3970)

Comment: diavolic ,  thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to go over an array and create a new one with a "row transformer" callback.
Or [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for simply looping over an array and do whatever you want.

```
var array = [
    {ID: 1, val: "make"},
    {ID: 2, val: "an"},
    {ID: 3, val: "useful"},
    {ID: 4, val: "sample"},
    {ID: 5, val: "please"}
]

var myNewArray = array.map(function(row, idx){
    return row.ID;
});
```